# Any way to run dotnet-ef from a published app

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm constructing a docker container from a Dotnet Core 2.0 WebApp that was packaged with `dotnet publish`, but publishing this way doesn't copy the extensions in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` that enable the `dotnet-ef` command.

Specifically, I want to run `dotnet ef` commands in the container, but I get this error:

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

My .csproj file contains this, so `dotnet-ef` works fine on the host:

```xml
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
```

Is there a way to run migrations from a dotnet app that's been packaged with `dotnet publish`?

Comment: See [Deploy EF Core Migrations from a DLL](https://www.benday.com/2017/03/17/deploy-entity-framework-core-migrations-from-a-dll/) by Ben Day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @bricelam's suggestion and [Ben Day's blog entry](https://www.benday.com/2017/03/17/deploy-entity-framework-core-migrations-from-a-dll/), this works for dotnet 2.x on Linux:

```
$ dotnet exec \
    --depsfile Api.deps.json \
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet/2.0.2/tools/netcoreapp2.0/ef.dll \
    database update \
    --assembly ./MyDllWithMigrations.dll \
    --startup-assembly Api.dll \
    --project-dir . \
    --verbose
```

(This is based on the `microsoft/aspnetcore-build` base image.)